# How to remove all non-numeric characters from a string in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Example:

```
file="123 hello"
```

How can I edit the string `file` such that it only contains the numbers and the text part is removed?

So,

```
echo $file
```

should print `123` only.

Answer (score 121):

This is one way with `sed`:

```
$ echo $file | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' 
123
$ echo "123 he23llo" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
12323
```

Or with pure `bash`:

```
$ echo "${file//[!0-9]/}" 
123
$ file="123 hello 12345 aaa"
$ echo "${file//[!0-9]/}" 
12312345
```

To save the result into the variable itself, do

```
$ file=$(echo $file | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
$ echo $file
123

$ file=${file//[!0-9]/}
$ echo $file
123
```

Comment: In the interest of completeness, you can also save the result back in the same variable with the pure bash form:  `file=${file//[!0-9]/}`.  Also, you can in general replace `echo ` *something* `|` *command* with *command* `<<<` *something*.

Comment: Good point, @MarkReed. As per the kind of user asking I preferred to leave the answer very naive, as `<<<` can be strange for people starting to bash-script. I update my answer with the `file=$file{file//[!0-9]/}`, many thanks!

Comment: Looking to do this for a version string (e.g. `git version 1.7.1`)? Use `${gitVersion//[!0-9.]/}` and it keeps the periods.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this command not delete whitespace in the string? This is actually the behavior I wanted, but don't understand why it's the default.

Comment: @LukeDavis not sure what you tried, but I tested and it does work: `file="hola que tal 23"` and then `echo "${file//[!0-9]/}"` returns 23.

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific (and I was mistaken). `echo hello 1 2 3 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'` (not your example) returns `1 2 3`, but your example, `echo hello 1 2 3 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`, returns `123`. Wondering why leaving out the `g` preserves spaces.

Comment: @LukeDavis `/g` stands for "global replacement". When used, any replacement is done as many times as possible within the line. Otherwise, as you just saw, it just happens once. Compare `sed 's/./X/' <<< "hello"` with `sed 's/./X/g' <<< "hello"` (spoiler: they return "Xello" and "XXXXX").

Answer (score 9):

You can say:

```
echo ${file%%[^0-9]*}
```

However, this runs into problems in certain cases:

```
$ file="123 file 456"
$ echo ${file%%[^0-9]*}
123
```

Using `tr`:

```
$ file="123 hello 456"
$ new=$(tr -dc '0-9' <<< $file)
$ echo $new
123456
```

Comment: "certain cases"?  `${file%%[^0-9]*}` will always remove everything from the first non-digit to the end of the string.  `%%` is not what you want here at all (nor is `%` or `#` or `##`).  I feel like I'm missing a joke here.

Comment: Dear @MarkReed, I thought that what you're saying was made clear in the answer itself, or not?  Probably that was the reason that another approach was suggested.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MarkReed Moreover, feel free to add your answer.  I'll be glad to delete this.

Comment: @devnull I'm just failing to understand the goal of bringing up an obviously incorrect solution before turning around and offering a correct one, and then commenting on your own answer asserting that there's something terribly wrong with it. Perhaps it's a pedagogical technique instead of a joke, but either way I fear it went over my head completely.

Comment: @devnull, I wish I could downvote comments. There's no place for personal attacks here.

Comment: I give +1 to this answer. The first solution may be useful in some simple cases like the example which was provided by the OP. So, I don't see any problems to propose this solution although I would have tendency to always use `sed`. Moreover, devnull has warned about the limitations of this first solution and gave another one that works well.

More solutions, more wealth.