# Get all numbers in a file using a line break as separator

Tags: sed, numbers

I have a file containing many blocks of lines. In each block, I have one numeric character of multiple digits (15353580 for instance). I need to extract all these numbers and put them as a column in a new file.

I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724531/how-to-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-bash). The `sed` command does the job but does not separate the numbers from each other. Using the second example ("123 he23llo") of the most voted response, I would like to have `123-23` instead of `12323`, where my '-' stands for a line break. How can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed -e 's/[^0-9]\+/-/g' -e 's/-$//'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "123 hel43lo 23fds" | sed -e 's/[^0-9]\+/-/g' -e 's/-$//'
123-43-23
```