# Awk the command output

Tags: shell, awk, grep

This is the command what i run.

```
ldap="$(ldapwhoami -x -H ldap://ABC.example.org -D "$user" -w "$pass")"
```

This is the output result:

```
u:ABC\1234567
```

May i know how to get the expected output ? like this `1234567`

Thanks

Comment: `your command | cut -d'\' -f2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all non-numeric characters from a string in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724531/how-to-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
echo "u:ABC\1234567" | awk -F'\' '{print $NF}'
```

***OR***

```
your_command | awk -F'\' '{print $NF}'
```

***2nd solution:*** using `awk`'s `sub` method.

```
your_command  | awk '{sub(/.*\\/,"")} 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "u:ABC\1234567" | sed "s/[^0-9]//g"
```

There is a way with SED.